# Best reactive way for a Java application to communicate with a node.js server

Tags: java, node.js, rx-java, reactive, bridge

I need a node.js server to run a third-party library which is great at interacting reactively with the ethereum blockchain. They don't have a Java implementation but my application is Java-based.

I need to make a call from my JVM container to the node.js container and have the result returned in a reactive way.

Which pattern/protocol should I use to implement this effectively?
e.g. A message bus, websockets, REST?

Comment: "rest api wrapper" ${select-a-lang}  any language will do while looking the same at the protocol level

Comment: Hi, I don't need a wrapper as I will be calling the node.js server with either restTemplate or OkHttpClient if I go down the REST route. Both of these implementations can be wrapped with something like RxJava to form a cohesive, reactive solution. What I'm more interested in is which of the examples I gave above is preferred and whether or not there is something else that I'm missing which is better fit for purpose? Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of theories about it, and it is also hard identifying which is the "best protocol" for it; it really depends by the use cases. In my company we have several microservices fully reactive that are communicating between each other via Websocket (using Webflux, Spring 5).

In your case (without the use cases I can't be detailed) the main benefit of using Websocket is the entire server is acting in an entirely reactive way, with a completely reactive stack.

Comment: I was leaning towards a reactive websocket model too. Excellent, thanks!